# Casting XamlComboBox to a inherited Type not working

Tags: c#, inheritance, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to cast a CodedUI `XamlControl` to a Type of a `XamlComboBox` but the cast throws a unable to cast exception.

My class is:

```
public class MyComboBox : XamlComboBox
```

The error occurs when i try to iterate over a `List<XamlControl>` in the following line:

```
var comboBox = (MyComboBox) element;
```

Even when i try something weird like this:

```
var xamlComboBox = (XamlComboBox) element;
var comboBox = (MyComboBox) xamlComboBox;
```

the error still hapens at cast to `MyComboBox`

Any idea, why this is happening?

Comment: what exactly is the error? - for me it seems, that you try to cast any `XamlControl`, which is not a `MyComboBox`, to `MyComboBox`

Comment: Is the element really a MyComboBox? Are you sure your List does not contain elements that are of type XamlComboBox but not MyComboBox?

Answer (score 1):

Before your iteration filter all items, which are not of type `MyComboBox`:

```
List<XamlControl> controls = ...
foreach (var comboBox in controls.Where(c => c is MyComboBox)) {
    // Here the items are only of type MyComboBox
}
```